# Developing a RESTful API with OAuth and/or OpenID

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, openid

Im struggling to wrap my head around implementing OAuth or OpenID with multiple external token providers. Since from my perspective the providers like google mix both specs in a single api, im differentiating these two mechanism in the way i protect my ressources and deal with user data. OpenID is only used for authentication and i produce my own access_tokens and persist all of the user data myself, while on the other hand OAuth provides external access_tokens and manages user data.

Entities involved:

1. **External provider** - which is my term for the OAuth/OpenID provider like Google OAuth
2. **Backend** - Server which serves primarily as a RESTful API for the clients
3. **Clients** - Apps (e.g SPA, IOS App, Desktop clients) which need to access ressources provided by the backend

Im developing an express backend (rest api) for several different sort of clients including web, ios/android. From my understanding i have the following options: (referring to most implementation docs of the provider i want to use instead of the spec)

**Option 1 - OpenID**

1. The client acquires an auth_code by signing in with any external provider (Apple, Google, Facebook)
2. The client sends this auth_code to my backend where this code is used to issue an id_token
3. The backend uses this id_token to authenticate the user and store any required  information about the user
4. The backend generates an access/refresh token for authorization and sends these back to the client
5. Now i can use my access_token for authorization and the refresh token for auth-state-management (signout, invalidate tokens)

Problem - Is there a problem really ?

- Im not sure if i need to frequently check if the user is still a *valid* identity. With valid identity i mean wether the external identity (e.g. google user) still exists, which basically relates to wether my persistance layer has to invalidate (delete) this user. In other words do i have to sync my persistance layer with the external provider to avoid *dead/unusable identities*. This is especially a problem if information like the email address changes and my backend does not get notified about that. Or should i just live with the fact that the user in my backend is just related to the external user by the id and the clients have to manage their data in my backend themselves (e.g change their email at the client). That would mean i preferable ignore any changes to the external user data (at the provider).

**Option 2 - OAuth**

1. The client acquires an auth_code by signing in with any external provider (SiwA (ios), Google, Facebook)
2. The client sends this auth_code to my backend where this code is used to issue an access_token/refresh_token from the provider
3. The backend sends back the access_token/refresh_token obtained from the external provider
4. Now everytime the client does make a request it has to contain the external access_token which then is used at the backend to ask the external provider if this token is valid and the client has access to the ressource. In other words i use the external access_token for authorization
5. Everytime user data (e.g. email, address...) is required at the backend, it is necessary to ask the external provider for this data by providing the access_token, which was given by the client

Problems/Questions:

- I assume that the refresh process has to be perfomed on client side in case the backend redirects unauthorized from the provider in case the token expires. Is that correct ?
- How do i determine from which provider the token is. It seems weird for me to implement a trial and error process and just ask every provider if this is a valid token. E.g. if the backend receives an access token in the header of the request it doesnt know which provider to ask. (or should i encode this information in the header like `Bearer Provider Token` in order to know where to check the access token.
- Using **Option 2**, anytime the external provider experiences downtime no user is able to use my backend, while with using **Option 1** only the signin (inital sigin or after explicity signing out, which invalidates the refresh token) is not availabe for this specific provider.

Is there anything i'm missing ? It seems to me that **Option 2** introduces a lot of unnecessary communication to the auth provider, while **Option 1** does neglect any communication which is potentially required (e.g. sync of identity state) ?
The main question for me is, considering **Option 1** which seems more suitable for my scenario, do i necessarily have to react to any state change of the user state, like change of email at the external provider or are there any downside to ignoring anything then the external user id to allow for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing OpenID, realizing i only needed authentication and no authorization nor rigorous coupling of user data. At the time of asking the question, i was aware of the difference, however i didn't dig deep enough into the requirements of my project. Thus i discarded the basic OAuth protocol, since i didn't need any authorization to external ressources.

Regarding OpenID, the management of external identities from the OpenID provider is not in the scope of the protocol it has to be done independently. There are other protocols and methods dealing with that e.g. [SCIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_for_Cross-domain_Identity_Management).

I ended up relying on the fact the the external id provided with id_token is unique and initialize a one time mapping at the first time authenticating (basically a signup). My server manages the user data from this moment on. Subsequent authentication request rely on the fact that this mapping never changes and any user data may differ compared to any data kept at the provider, e.g. different mail addresses at my server compared to the google mail of the external identityl. However this doesn't violate my requirements.

Furthermore, i want to add that i ended up supporting implicit flow and auth code flow, which means the client can send the id_token directly, instead of sending the auth_code. I did not fully get the point why this is more unsecure since from my current perspective my server ask the provider to verify the id_token which prevents any malicious intends by proividing false id_tokens.